# Change Border Color of Border on Table- Kable

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra

I am trying to create borders around specific columns in **R**. I am able to do this using the kableExtra package (shown below)

```
iris <- datasets::iris

iris2 <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ Species, iris, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))

res2 <- kable(iris2,"html", col.names =  c("Species", "Mean", "SD", "Mean", "SD", "Mean", "SD", "Mean", "SD"),   align = c("r","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c")) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Sepal Length" = 2, "Sepal Width" = 2, "Petal Length" = 2, "Petal Width" = 2))

print(res2)

res3<- column_spec(res2, c(2,4,6,8), border_left = TRUE, border_right = FALSE)

column_spec(res3, c(3,5,7,9), border_left = FALSE, border_right = TRUE)
```

This creates the border I would like in the right positions, but I would like them to be gray and not black. I tried using the 'color=' from the column_spec function but it turns the whole column gray and not just the border.

```
res3<- column_spec(res2, c(2,4,6,8), border_left = TRUE, border_right = FALSE, color = "#D8D7D7")
column_spec(res3, c(3,5,7,9), border_left = FALSE, border_right = TRUE, color = "#D8D7D7")
```

Any suggestions on how to change the border color would be helpful! For now, I am using `getAnywhere()` to see if I can just change the function slightly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use css into a border. This works

```
column_spec(res3, c(3,5,7,9), border_left = "2px solid gray",
            border_right = "2px solid gray")
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not too familiar with cascading style sheets, this opens up some new windows for me! Couldn't tell the difference in color at first and had to change it to "2px solid lightgray". Works perfectly.

Comment: How can we do the same for rows?